# How to make DateTime update automatically without refreshing the page in html and razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have ASP.NET application in which I have Date and Time displayed but I want seconds number to roll on every second without refreshing the page

I am displaying the Date and Time using the following line

```
<p>@DateTime.Now</p>
```

Can I get the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to display server time or local client time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a little javascript to do that. you can't do it server side.

you can use setInterval(1000) and set the value of the element to the time every second.

Comment: What if the server and client are in different time zones?

Comment: @Captain . I am doing it the following way as you said http://jsfiddle.net/V3SxL/28/ but its giving me the wrong month and I want client time.

Comment: @Dayakar, The month is actually correct. January starts at 0. So December would be 11. Change it to `(now.getMonth()+1)` for the representation you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in your razor view but there are a ton of ways to do this in javascript. A few examples:

- PURE JAVASCRIPT: http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/creating-a-javascript-clock/clock.html
- ANGULAR: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (search for "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM")

There are lots of other examples out there - search google and you should find them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a server time do a jquery ajax call and retrieve the correct server time from an ajaxworker page.